# Continous Communication with netcat

Tags: linux, bash, shell, netcat

I have a bash script and i need to communicate with a server with netcat.
I want to do

1.Connect with nc
2.Read Answer
3.Decide what to do with answer
4.Send a data to server
5.Go back to 2

Here is my code. But It does not advance after echo $JOB_STRING | netcat $BAGLANTI $PORT

```
$(echo $JOB_STRING | netcat $BAGLANTI $PORT)  
  read line    
  if [[ $line == "2.7" ]]; then
    echo Sunucu Verisyonu $line
---Send something to nc server
  else
    echo "İş geldi"
---Send something to nc server
  fi
```

I've also tried to store response in a variable but that didn't work too

```
    RESPONSE="$(echo $JOB_STRING | nc $BAGLANTI $PORT)"
  if [[ $RESPONSE "2.7" ]]; then
    echo Sunucu Verisyonu $line
  else
    echo "İş geldi"
  fi
```

Comment: ```while true; do echo "run"; sleep 2; done```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually i couldn't understand where do i request an answer from server in this script. Can you explain?

Comment: see Antonio answer

Comment: Yes I've tried it but no luck.

Comment: What's the output of the command `<<<$JOB_STRING netcat -v $BAGLANTI $PORT`?

Comment: `with netcat` Does it _have to_ be netcat? Why not write it like python for example? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953206/read-and-write-to-the-same-netcat-tcp-connection answer your question?

Comment: What do you even mean by `netcat`?  There's hobbit's `nc` and nmap's `ncat`.  If you haven't looked at nmap's `ncat`, you should.

Comment: @KamilCuk there is a phyton program already for this but i just wonderen if i can do it in bash directly

Comment: @WilliamPursell i will.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```sh
while read line; do

  if [[ $line == "2.7" ]]; then
    echo Sunucu Verisyonu $line
  else
    echo "İş geldi"
  fi

done < $(echo $JOB_STRING | netcat $BAGLANTI $PORT)
```

**Edit:**

```sh
echo $JOB_STRING | netcat $BAGLANTI $PORT | while read line; do

  if [[ $line == "2.7" ]]; then
    echo Sunucu Verisyonu $line
  else
    echo "İş geldi"
  fi

done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't solved. It's still doesn't advance.

Comment: I don't have your environment, so I cannot reproduce it enterely. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Actually i've just noticed. Your code doesn't stuck. but it gives `line 19: $(echo $JOB_STRING | netcat $BAGLANTI $PORT): No such file or directory` error.

Comment: You are right, I edited my post. Please try again...

Comment: Still no luck. Doesn't echo either of them and terminates script. Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

So run the command in the background and connect two fifos to it - one for reading, the other for writing - and use those two fifos to communicate with the background process. The background process is, of course, the netcat instance. With newer bash, coproc is a built-in command that does just that, and it's just trivial to use.

```
coproc netcat $BAGLANTI $PORT
echo JOB something >&"${COPROC[1]}"
IFS= read -r line  <&"${COPROC[0]}"
if something; then
    echo some response >&"${COPROC[1]}"
fi
exec {COPROC[0]}>&- {COPROC[1]>&-
kill $COPROC_PID
```